# How can I store the new CHANGESET number in my source code after I check in?

Tags: tfs, changeset

In SVN you can use some [keyword expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328724/how-can-i-store-the-new-svn-revision-number-in-my-source-code-after-i-commit-t) to put your revision number inside source files. I find this particularly useful on SQL scripts.

Using TFS2010, how can I put the changeset number inside a source file ?

Comment: Why is it useful? Can't you just query the source control history when you actually need to know about the changeset?

Comment: I'd like to know why you find this useful

Comment: To control part of my production environment. Many people (not just from the IT-DEV team) can make changes on SQL scripts on my current job, and sometimes, after a database restore do development environment, we find that some key functions and procedure were changed, and with the changeset I can track if the routine changed matches the one on the source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really must insert the current changeset number in a file, you can use the [Keyword Substitution Check-in Policy](http://logsubstpol.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Nice, but seems a bit complicate. Doesn't TFS have a built-in support for this ?

Comment: No.  And, although I'm biased, having worked on a TFS client for several years, I think that changing the contents of your files after checking them in and having them appear "unmodified" is perhaps not intuitive.